# Python+ubuntu error

Tags: python, ubuntu

Am trying to run the following python program

```
import re
regex=re.compile("http...imgs.xkcd.com.comics.[\\S]*.[jpg|png]")
f=open('out.txt')
for a in f:
    print regex.findall(a)
    print '\n'
```

when I type the code into the interpreter manually, it works as expected
but when i save it as a file and try to run it , it gives errors.
The command i used to run it is

```
chmod +x 
sudo ./pymod.py
```

ERROR:
    ./pymod.py: 2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

if i dont use sudo, the error i get is

```
./pymod.py: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./pymod.py: line 2: `regex=re.compile("http...imgs.xkcd.com.comics.[\\S]*.[jpg|png]")'
```

am using ubuntu 10.04 with everything on default

it takes about 10-15 seconds for the error to appear

Comment: python pymod.py worked as suggested by Santiago Lezica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set something as executable, you have to specify what you want it to run it with, or Linux will consider it to be a bash script.

Add this as the first line of the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Or run it like:

```
python pymod.py
```

Cheers!

Comment: If it tried to run the file as a binary, you'd get very different errors ;) No, it runs bash. Otherwise, yeah.

Comment: Corrected. Thanks! Edit: LOL just saw the output he posted, I didn't even read it, of course it would throw very different errors.

Answer (score 3):

Your file should start with shebang. You should include the path to the python interpreter

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re
regex=re.compile("http...imgs.xkcd.com.comics.[\\S]*.[jpg|png]")
```

Check out : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

Answer (score 2):

This is probably executing as a bash script instead of in Python.  Put

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

at the beginning of your script.

Answer (score 0):

Either use the "shebang". I.e. put

```
#! /usr/bin/python
```

as the first line of your script.
Or teach your ubuntu how to treat python scripts without it 
as described here: http://www.daniweb.com/code/snippet241988.html